# Process many csv files in a loop and extract rows from non-empty cells of a specific column using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am made a code to process many csv files. For each one of them, I want to extract all rows corresponding to non-empty cells of a column called "20201-2.0". Have a look in the attached example (this is column LCE):

https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fgpapanas%5Fed%5Fac%5Fuk%2FDocuments%2FCSV%20File%20screenshot%2EPNG&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fgpapanas%5Fed%5Fac%5Fuk%2FDocuments&originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly91b2UtbXkuc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb20vOmk6L2cvcGVyc29uYWwvZ3BhcGFuYXNfZWRfYWNfdWsvRWF5QmJsRlRIbVZKdlJmc0I2aDhWcjRCMDlJZmpRMkwxSTVPUUtVTjJwNXd6dz9ydGltZT10V2Y0c2Q1UzEwZw

I made the following code to perform this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = './'
#column = ['20201-2.0']

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for filename in all_files:

    # Option 1 below worked, although without isolating the non-nulled values
    # 1. df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = 0)
    df = df[df['20201-2.0'].notnull()]

    print('extracting info from cvs...')
    print(df)

    # You can now export all outcomes in new csv files
    file_name = filename + 'new' + '.csv'
    save_path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            path, file_name
        )
    )
    print('saving ...')
    export_csv = df.to_csv(save_path, index=None)

    del df
    del export_csv
```

However, although I manage to generate the first file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '20201-2.0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/OPTIMAT/Read_MR_from_all_csv.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = df[df['20201-2.0'].notnull()]
  File "/home/giorgos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '20201-2.0'
```

I can't understand why this is happening. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to say that I found a way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import numpy as np

path = './'
#column = ['20201-2.0']

# all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

#li = []
all_files = os.listdir(path)
all_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in all_files:
    if not filename.endswith('csv'):
        continue

    print('extracting info from ' + filename)
    # Option 1 below worked, although without isolating the non-nulled values
    # 1. df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    #df = df[df['20201-2.0'].notnull()]

    df_subset = df.dropna(subset=['20201-2.0'])
    print('processed ' + filename)

    # You can now export all outcomes in new csv files
    file_name = filename.split('.')[0] + '_new' + '.csv'

    print('saving to' + file_name)
    export_csv = df_subset.to_csv('./' + file_name, index=None)

    del df
    del export_csv
```